# Enable component specific hot reloading?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, hot-reload

I created a react app using the following:

> create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts

From following this example: https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript

I tried adding:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

To my index.tsx but I only get full page refreshes when I change a nested component.

For example I create a component like this:

```
const MediaGrid = (props: any) => {
    return (<div>hello</div>);
}
```

and place it in a root component:

```
class Home extends Component<{ }, { }>{

    render() {
        return <div>
<h2>some stuff</h2>
            <MediaGrid />
        </div>;
    }
}
```

If I change MediaGrid only the entire page refreshes including Home and all other components in Home.

I've seen React projects with component specific hot reloading and want to achieve the same result so that if I change MediaGird only that will refresh.

I tried following steps here for typescript: https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/pull/312#issuecomment-387974687

My webpack.config.dev.js:

```
'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const paths = require('./paths');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = '/';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_PATH%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.
const publicUrl = '';
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// This is the development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience and fast rebuilds.
// The production configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  // You may want 'eval' instead if you prefer to see the compiled output in DevTools.
  // See the discussion in https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/343.
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  // These are the "entry points" to our application.
  // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
  // The first two entry points enable "hot" CSS and auto-refreshes for JS.
  entry: [
    // We ship a few polyfills by default:
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
    // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
    // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
    // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
    // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
    // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
    // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
    // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
    // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
    // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    // Finally, this is your app's code:
    paths.appIndexJs,
    // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
    // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
    // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
  ],
  output: {
    // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
    pathinfo: true,
    // This does not produce a real file. It's just the virtual path that is
    // served by WebpackDevServer in development. This is the JS bundle
    // containing code from all our entry points, and the Webpack runtime.
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    // This is the URL that app is served from. We use "/" in development.
    publicPath: publicPath,
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/253
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
    // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/290
    // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
    // for React Native Web.
    extensions: [
      '.mjs',
      '.web.ts',
      '.ts',
      '.web.tsx',
      '.tsx',
      '.web.js',
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.web.jsx',
      '.jsx',
    ],
    alias: {

      // Support React Native Web
      // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
      // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
      // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
      // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
      // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: paths.appTsConfig }),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      // TODO: Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      // We are waiting for https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2176.
      // { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        loader: require.resolve('source-map-loader'),
        enforce: 'pre',
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
        // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
        // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
        oneOf: [
          // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
          // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
          // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {

              compact: true,
            },
          },

          // Compile .tsx?

          {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                  babelrc: false,
                  plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],
                },
              },
              'ts-loader', // (or awesome-typescript-loader)
            ],
          },
          // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
          // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
          // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
          // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
          // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
          // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
          // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
          // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
          // that fall through the other loaders.
          {
            // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
            // its runtime that would otherwise processed through "file" loader.
            // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
            // by webpacks internal loaders.
            exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
      // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In development, this will be an empty string.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    // Add module names to factory functions so they appear in browser profiler.
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
    // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/240
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
    // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
    // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
    // See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/186
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
    // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
    // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
    // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
    // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
    // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    // Perform type checking and linting in a separate process to speed up compilation
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      async: false,
      watch: paths.appSrc,
      tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
      tslint: paths.appTsLint,
    }),
  ],
  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
  // Turn off performance hints during development because we don't do any
  // splitting or minification in interest of speed. These warnings become
  // cumbersome.
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

My app.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import rootStore from './redux/store'

import './App.css';

import AppContext from './context/AppContext';
import Header from './components/header';
import LoginPopup from './components/LoginPopup';
import Home from './pages/Home';

import logo from './logo.svg';
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';



import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import SubmitPopup from './components/SubmitPopup';
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "snip",
  authDomain: "hadaka-2.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://hadaka-2.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "hadaka-2",
  storageBucket: "hadaka-2.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "305148376063"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (<Provider store={rootStore}>
      <div className="App">
        <AppContext>
          <LoginPopup />
          <SubmitPopup />
          <Header />
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
          </header>

          <Home />
          <p className="App-intro">
            To get started, edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        </AppContext>
      </div>
    </Provider>
    );
  }
}


export default hot(module)(App);
```

Sometimes it works but more often the whole page reloads...

it seems to work every second time, for example if I add a new div like hello the component itself reloads, if I add another div like hello 2 or delete the div I added the whole page reloads which makes me think there's something else at play here trying to do a full screen refresh..

Comment: Can you add more informations?

Comment: @gg_ I added more details, hope it makes things clearer!

Comment: https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/pull/312#issuecomment-387974687

Comment: @gg_ I tried following the steps there, the results were mixed, sometimes the components reloaded and sometimes the page refreshes. not sure if I messed up somewhere else or perhaps the project comes with baked in full page reload which kicks in first.. I updated my question with my changes

Comment: I think you may have misconfigured webpack if i remeber corectly when you use `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` you don't have to setup additional entry point or use `--hot` flag when starting devserver for comparision look for hmr flags in here https://github.com/Xesenix/xes-webpack-core/blob/master/src/webpack/webpack.config.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use the [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) module. Just follow the getting started section.

Also, do not forget to modify the `npm start` script to `node scripts/start.js -- --hot`

I have created a demo repo for this. Please have a look at this: https://github.com/shishiranshuman/react-ts-hot-reloading-example

Demo: [image]

Comment: I'm marking this question as the answer because it was very helpful in me finding the solution to my problem which was that in app.tsx I had a firebase initialization happening (firebase.initailizeApp(config), removing that fixed the odd issue with hot reloading only working every second time. Will raise issue on github.